# NSMutableString Append Fails

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I have an `NSString` that I'd like to append a `{` at the beginning of it.

```
 NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"{"];
    [str stringByAppendingString:extracted];
```

This returns `str` with only `{`. Why is that? Objective-C is VERY frustrating with how it provides many ways of doing the same thing, yet for situations a different way is required.

I tried doing `[NSMutableString string]` and appending `{` then `extracted` and it still does not work. Why is this not working and what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stringByAppendingString` returns a new string, it does not modify the old string.

All functions that begins with `stringWith` or `arrayWith` etc. create new objects rather than modifying old objects.

To acheive what you want, a simpler solution is:

```
 NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%@", oldString];
```

or:

```
 NSMutableString *str = [@"{" mutableCopy];
 [str appendString:blah];
```

Comment: (release or autorelease `str` if not using ARC)

Answer (score 5):

You are calling an `NSString` method that returns a new string and does not modify the string that it is called on. You need to call [`appendString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/appendString:).

```
[str appendString:extracted];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// use it like this

NSString *extracted = @"this is my string";
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"{"];
str =  [str stringByAppendingString:extracted];
```

Hope this will help you